# Fastest way to modify array values?

Tags: perl

Is there a faster way  ( faster than foreach) to modify each value of an array?

```
my @array = ( 'file1.c', 'file2.h', 'file3.py');
foreach ( my $elemeny ( @array)) {
    #remove extension
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by fast? Faster to write or faster to run?

Comment: Faster to run, i guess

Comment: Why do you need it fast? How many elements are in your array? How complex is the operation you are going to do? [The first rule of optimization is don't do it.](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?RulesOfOptimization)

Comment: I have a hash with about 30 keys. The values of those keys are arrays with aprox 30 elements.
I don't necessary need it, i just want to know it. Are there fastest ways?

Comment: Fast always depends on the specs of your machine (that includes memory, CPU speed, speed of disks), on the code you run, on the availability of resources (CPU load, other programs running at the same time, disk i/o, ...) and possibly on a lot of other factors. You can [benchmark](http://blogs.perl.org/users/steffen_mueller/2010/09/your-benchmarks-suck.html) your code against other implementations, but that will only tell you about the results at that particular time on your machine. For this specific question, a loop is a loop. You have to iterate all elements. There is no way around that.

Answer (score 4):

A *shorter* way of writing the same thing:

```
s/\.[^.]+$// foreach @array;
```

Comment: This is probably _faster to write_, but _not necessarily faster to read_.